# How to check if a username is taken, by checking against a JavaScript array.

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var y=document.forms["form"]["user"].value
    if (y==null || y=="" )
        {
            alert("Username cannot be Blank");
            return false;
        };

var x = new Array();
    x[0] = "bill";  
    x[1] = "ted";   
    x[2] = "jim";   
    for ( keyVar in x ) 
        {
            if (x==y)
            {
                alert("Username Taken");
                return false;
            };

        };
```

How do I compare a variable to that in a JavaScript array, I managed to make the example above, but the second part, the bit I need, doesn't work. any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an object instead:

```
var y = document.forms["form"]["user"].value;
if (y == null || y == "") {
    alert("Username cannot be Blank");
    return false;
};

var x = {};
x["bill"] = true;
x["ted"] = true;
x["jim"] = true;
if (x[y] === true) {
    alert("Username Taken");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply check an array with the `Array.prototype.indexOf` method.

```
var x = [ 'bill', 'ted', 'jim' ],
    y = 'ted';

if( x.indexOf( y ) > -1 ) {
    alert('Username Taken');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think that indexOf is much  slower than checking if the property of an object is true (and this get more relevant as the array grows in size)

Comment: @Nicola this is probably the most straight forward answer since the OP wants to search against an array.  If the array was sorted then we could use a binary search.  Otherwise, using an object would probably yield better results... (keys/values, TRIE etc)

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti: the array would need to become really huge before performance becomes an issue. However, ES.next will solve all the problems, weakmaps are coming :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite simply with jQuery

The list of the array values

```
var x = new Array();
x[0] = "bill";  
x[1] = "ted";   
x[2] = "jim";
```

then

```
 if(jQuery.inArray("John", arr) == -1){
     alert("Username Taken");
 }
```

Comment: There is no jQuery involved here  i think